# Subtract X# of days from today's date and exclude weekends and holiday

Tags: excel

I have today's date auto populating in C2 using **=TODAY()** and I need to subtract 8 days from it, excluding weekends and holidays. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Check this [article](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-networkdays-function#:~:text=The%20Excel%20NETWORKDAYS%20function%20calculates,of%20holidays%20supplied%20as%20dates.)

Comment: Workday or workday.intl https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-workday-function

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it to work using WORKDAY.
=WORKDAY(C2, -8, Holidays)